# LINQ Lambda efficiency of code groupby orderby

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have this code, but I think that it could run faster, or I just hope to. But I have plenty of data. I'd like to have it as effective as it can be.

Here is the code:

(Need to return newest translations of words (Language and value) from resources grouped by resource and language based on `Expression<Func<ResourcesTranslation, bool>> ConditionExpression`)

```
KeyValues = item.Resources
                .Where(ConditionExpression)
                .GroupBy(g => new { g.ResourceId, g.Language })                  
                .Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(o => o.Changed ?? o.Created))
                .Select( s => new KeyValues
                {
                    Language = s.FirstOrDefault().Language,
                    KeyValue = s.FirstOrDefault().Value
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Use ToListAsync() instead of ToList().

Comment: Why do you need 2 selects? Provide please your model data.

Comment: Cause id like to get to value from group and have it ordered

Comment: @BorHunter  and Select can't be like: .Select(m => m.OrderByDescending(o => o.Changed.HasValue ? o.Changed : o.Created), m => new KeyValues{...})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Visual Studio translates it in to selects, so I realized that, the best solution for stuff like this is to make some View.. Just giving answer to own Q for another guys.

Answer (score 2):

As you need only one element after grouping, you can return it right in GroupBy clause, it will simplify your code:

```
KeyValues = item.Resources
    .Where(ConditionExpression)
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.ResourceId, g.Language }, 
         (x, y) => new { Max = y.OrderByDescending(o => o.Changed ?? o.Created).First() })
    .Select(s => new KeyValues
    {
        Language = s.Max.Language,
        KeyValue = s.Max.Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer was helpful for you by clicking the check-mark @Qhori

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can get some performance by removing the first,  unneeded select (depending  on the volume of data this could be minimal to medium improvement) like this:

```
KeyValues = item.Resources
                .Where(ConditionExpression)
                .GroupBy(g => new { g.ResourceId, g.Language })                  
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Changed.HasValue ? o.Changed : o.Created)
                .Select( s => new KeyValues
                {
                    Language = s.Language,
                    KeyValue = s.Value
                }).ToList();
```

Depending on your case,  you could:

1. If your data is in a database, you can create database improvements like adding indexes,  updating statistics, using hints etc.
2. if this is local data, you can use some strategy to split new and old data between various enumerables.

There is no other way to significantly improve your linq query. You need to find another strategy to achieve that.

Comment: that orderbydesc must be in select, cause you can't get value of Changed and Created from group...